# CSS-only image slider problems on safari

Tags: html, css, image, safari, slider

I have a CSS-only image slider on my website. It works perfectly except on Safari tablet/mobile devices. It's very strange though because the slider just doesn't work on these mobile devices when you go to the slider page directly from my homepage. (If you refresh the page, of if you go directly to the slider page without going to the home page first, it works on these devices in Safari). I have no idea how to fix this, if someone could help please let me know!

Here is the link to my website:
http://averyeliasdesign.com

If you scroll down to the "Work" section and click on one of the work samples, it will take you to the page with the slider.

The link to the slider page is: 
http://averyeliasdesign.com/work1.html 
If you click on this direct link from your phone, the slider will work. It just doesn't work when you go to the slider page from my homepage.

Comment: Here's a jsfiddle with my code: 
http://jsfiddle.net/averyelias/yupf9v9t/

Comment: It seems to be working.

Comment: It will work if you click directly on the link using your phone. But if you are on my website www.averyeliasdesign.com and then click on one of my work samples (which takes you to averyeliasdesign.com/work) the slider doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

It is working on my iOS 8.4 device (5th generation iPod touch).

Comment: Did you try going to averyeliasdesign.com first and then clicking on one of my work samples (which takes you to the slider page). If you click directly on the slider link then it will work on your phone. It's so strange!